# How do I spawn a skeleton with enchanted leather armor riding a creeper?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I wanna spawn a skeleton with full leather with all **MAX** blast protection riding a creeper. And so the command I came out with is this:

```
/summon Skeleton 16 53 -21 {Equipment:[{},{id:leather_boots,tag:{ench:[{id:3,lvl:4}]}},{id:leather_leggings,tag:{ench:[{id:3,lvl:4}]}},{id:leather_chestplate,tag:{ench:[{id:3,lvl:4}]}},{id:leather_helmet,tag:{ench:[{id:3,lvl:4}]}}]},Riding:{id:Creeper}}
```

But it doesn't work. It does say:

```
[11:56:34] Data tag parsing failed: Unbalanced square brackets []: {Equipment:[{},{id:leather_boots,tag:{ench:[{id:3,lvl:4}]}},{id:leather_leggings,tag:{ench:[{id:3,lvl:4}]}},{id:leather_chestplate,tag:{ench:[{id:3,lvl:4}]}},{id:leather_helmet,tag:{ench:[{id:3,lvl:4}]}]},Riding:{id:Creeper}
```

Answer (score 1):

You messed up with balancing []s.

```
/summon Skeleton 16 53 -21 {Equipment:[{},{id:leather_boots,tag:{ench:[{id:3,lvl:32767}]}},{id:leather_leggings,tag:{ench:[{id:3,lvl:32767}]}},{id:leather_chestplate,tag:{ench:[{id:3,lvl:32767}]}},{id:leather_helmet,tag:{ench:[{id:3,lvl:32767}]}}]}
```

Why did i use 32767 instead of 4? Because the max level enchant is 32767. The `lvl` tag is a short which in java is 2^(16-1) - 1 or 32767. The max level avalibe in survival minecraft is 4, but in game is 32767.

Comment: okay that nice but how do i ride the skeleton on a creeper i did ,Riding:{id:Creeper} but it wont work

Comment: Make sure you only put this in a command block (it is too long for chat) and that the ",Riding:{id:Creeper}" goes inside the outermost set of curly braces

`/summon Skeleton 16 53 -21 {Equipment:[{},{id:leather_boots,tag:{ench:[{id:3,lvl:32767}]}},{id:leather_leggings,tag:{ench:[{id:3,lvl:32767}]}},{id:leather_chestplate,tag:{ench:[{id:3,lvl:32767}]}},{id:leather_helmet,tag:{ench:[{id:3,lvl:32767}]}}],Riding:{id:Creeper}}`

Comment: it did work, really thnx. :P